# Migrate Database from 2007 to 2013

Tags: migration

I want to migrate my database from SP 2007 to 2013 directly.
My 2007 database has only one form, so we planned to create a same form in 2013 and copy the database.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. You must upgrade first to 2010.

Technet:

> You cannot upgrade directly from the server products in the Office
>   2007 release to SharePoint 2013. The changes between versions are too
>   great, and the hardware requirements differ so much between versions
>   that a direct upgrade is not possible or supported. However, you can
>   perform a series of database-attach upgrades to first upgrade your
>   content to SharePoint 2010 Products and then to SharePoint 2013. This
>   article describes how to perform these sequential database-attach
>   upgrades.

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee947141.aspx

An alternative is 3rd party vendor migration tool: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ronalg/archive/2013/01/28/can-i-upgrade-from-sharepoint-2007-directly-to-sharepoint-2013.aspx